# How to password protect my ps3 console

Tags: ps3

Can anyone let me know how to prevent others from using my ps3 console by using a password,just like a PC does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't lock out a user from your local account, but here's a few tricks I used to keep people from using my PS3

**Protecting your Online Account**

First, and easiest, uncheck the option to '*Remember Password*' for your PSN (online) account. this will stop people from being able to play as you and ruin your reputation/stats online.

**Password Prompt when Starting Games***

Next, you want to go into *Settings*->*Security Settings*->*Parental Control* It will ask you for a passcode, enter one (make sure you remember it).

Set the parental control level to 1 (the strictest) and when prompted, check the box that says "*Restrict Starting a game with no Parental Control Settings*" and click OK.

**Password Prompt when Starting Internet Browser**

If you want to restrict access to the Internet browser as well, go back to *Parental Control* and choose *Internet Browser Start Control*.

Enter your password, and change the setting to On

**Password Prompt when attempting to playback DVDs/BluRay disks**

You can even restrict access to DVD & Blu Ray disks as well, these options are under *Security Settings* again, this time choose *DVD - Parental Control* and *BD Parental Control* respectively.

Enter your password, and again change the setting to On

* : This will restrict games on discs as well as games downloaded from the Playstation Store.

Comment: awesome Robotnik...let me check out and let you know...but does the "Password Prompt when Starting Games" work for all games read from blueray,downloaded from PSN etc..

Comment: @ashwinsakthi - You have to enter the password to access the PSN Store in order to purchase and download a game.

Comment: @Ramhound yea but what if the game is already downloaded?

Comment: @Ender - I assume it works on the rating system of the game itself - and because you set it to the strictest level, it should always prompt. I haven't got any downloaded games (my net is pretty terrible so I never bothered using the PS Store) but what would be the point of restricting an R-rated disk and not an R-rated downloadable game?

Comment: This solution has mixed results. On a PS3 with multiple accounts, adding Parental Control to my account added it to all accounts... all with the same Parent PIN. Meaning it didn't divert a child away from my account, it made a child furious that nothing on the machine works without the PIN, which is easily visible while you type it in, by the way. It also blurs every game icon and name so you have to kind of navigate the home screen blind. I think we need a better solution... .