# Can I natively use my PS4's hard drive as a networked hard drive?

Tags: ps4

I bought a PS4 with 1TB hard drive, My idea was to use the PS4 as a Network-connected hard drive I can access with my notebook.

Is this even possible without modification or networking expertise? If so, How do I set it up?

Comment: I doubt that's possible. The PS4 is a console; a device meant for media consumption and primarily for gaming. Unlike the PS3, you can't install a different OS either, so there goes your network drive.

Comment: "media consumption" thats what I heard. But how do I get my media on it?

Comment: I wouldn't have bought a 1TB one, if I knew you can't use it for anything else than games ;)

Comment: @AshwinGupta while I agree, your comment is not constructive and so I've flagged it as such, feel free to edit it inline with what's expected on the network. Thanks :)

Comment: @djsmiley2k fair enough... I fixed it.

Comment: @Timelord64 While I dont care i the slightest, your argument would suggest that you would have to close many many other questions, like the ones in the related bar, such as "Can I play movie files on PS4".

Comment: @Timelord64 - Eh, that doesn't seem right - we support gaming specific hardware and utilities, even when they are not primarily about gaming. (Even if the answer to this one is 'You can't')

Comment: @Timelord64 -  What? What gives you that idea? We've always supported video games **and** video game hardware/software, it's right there as [one of the five primary coverage points of Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour). Hell, my first ever answer on Arqade was about [password protection on a PS3 console](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/82639/28182). Of course 'anything is possible' if you wanna break out your soldering iron, but the OP is not looking for a hack or a workaround, he's looking to see if it's currently supported natively by the PS4.

Comment: (cont.) and based on our collective expertise and knowledge of the PS4's current architecture, supported apps and functionality, the answer is 'It's not supported' as @djsmiley2k has covered in the answer.

Comment: @Timelord64 - He asked the gaming experts, so the context is whether it's supported in a way that your average gamer can understand. If OP wanted help to hack his PS4, **that** would be off-topic as an IT-related exercise.

Comment: @Robotnik, I have edited the question to expressly ask for native support. OP is the only one that sets context for the question, not where it is listed. If we assumed OP was asking the right place from the start, SE would not have a migrate feature (as opposed to Arqade not having a migrate feature because we wernt using it properly)

Comment: @Timelord64 - Ok cool. Btw the reason we don't have proper migration paths set up is that migration should always be a last resort. We consider questions as to their on-topicness here first, with migration only coming in if it's clear that it's blatantly off topic here but would be an acceptable question somewhere else on SE. So yeah, it's safe to assume OPs asked in the right place first - anything asked here *should* fit into gaming and should be primarily viewed from a gaming perspective. (Not to say that other expertise isn't welcome, but it's usually not a requirement) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the PS4 storage isn't designed to be used in this way.

You can view/consume media on your PS4 which maybe stored elsewhere on your network but you cannot, currently share your content from your PS4 to other devices other than when you view games remotely via a service such as PS Vita's remote play, or PS TV.

However, you can easily use up a large chunk of that storage once you start getting a few games, and some of the large patches they come with and so you may be glad of having the larger drive to start with (rather than upgrading in the future).